# Map multiple rows to create new columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':pd.Series(['id1','id2','id3']),
                    'DoB':pd.Series(['15/2','12/3','25/12']),
                    'Surgery Date':pd.Series(['1/1','2/1','3/1'])})

df2 = {'1':pd.Series(['id1', 'test1', '45']),
        '2':pd.Series(['id1', 'test2', '423']),
        '3':pd.Series(['id1', 'test3', '5']),
        '4':pd.Series(['id2', 'test2', '421'])}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)
df2 = df2.rename(index={0,:'id'})
df2 = df2.rename(index={1,:'test name'})
df2 = df2.rename(index={2,:'test value'})
```

I would like to merge these two so that df1 contains a new column for each test name, with the tests value underneath, for each id. I.e.:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':pd.Series(['id1','id2','id3']),
                    'DoB':pd.Series(['15/2',12/3','25/12']),
                    'Surgery Date':pd.Series(['1/1','2/1','3/1']),
                    'Test1':pd.Series([45]),
                    'Test2':pd.Series([426,421])})
```

Each ID has a different number of tests, and I'd like the code to work on a much larger database.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I break down the steps ..

```
df2=df2.T.set_index(['id','test name']).unstack()
df2.columns=df2.columns.droplevel()
df1.merge(df2,left_on='ID',right_index=True,how='left')
Out[457]: 
     DoB   ID Surgery Date test1 test2 test3
0   15/2  id1          1/1    45   423     5
1   12/3  id2          2/1  None   421  None
2  25/12  id3          3/1   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get an error: Series object has no attribute columns

Comment: @ConorMac why you have Series? Your sample input list above all dataframe